# How to handle default value in where clause '9999-01-01 00:00:00.000'

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
    u.FirstName, MiddleName, u.LastName, u.Address,
    u.Address2, u.City, u.State UserState, 
    u.PostalCode, u.Country, DateOfBirth
FROM 
    Users u
INNER JOIN 
    Companies c ON c.CompanyID = u.CompanyID
WHERE
    -- Users active/logged in within last 365 days
    u.ActiveEnd BETWEEN DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, getdate()) - 12, 0)
                    AND DATEADD(DD, -1, DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, getdate()), 0))  
    --all Active Companies or Companies deactivated within the last 60 days
    OR c.ActiveEnd BETWEEN DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, getdate()) - 2, 0) 
                       AND DATEADD(DD, -1, DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, getdate()), 0))
```

Here by default 'ACTIVEEND' column value is '9999-01-01 00:00:00.000' in entire table on both `Users` and `Companies` table.

I do not understanding how to write a condition to handle/manage for this default value as well in my above where clause.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: How does the default column value have any impact on the logic in your query?  Presumably columns wtith a `9999` default value would fail the `WHERE` clause, but then again wouldn't that be expected behavior?

Comment: if you entered into DB `9999` for a year- you're doomed

Comment: @T.S., lots of older or poorly built software uses roll-your-own default dates like this one in whatever proprietary RDBMS they are using rather than nulls if the source RDBMS does not support nulls. It makes things interesting when that data is pulled from another source or migrated to a properly built RDBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to exclude those default dates, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT 
    u.FirstName, MiddleName,u.LastName,u.Address,
    u.Address2, u.City,u.State UserState,u.PostalCode,u.Country,DateOfBirth
FROM 
    Users u
    INNER JOIN Companies c ON c.CompanyID = u.CompanyID
WHERE
    -- date is not default
    u.ActiveEnd != '9999-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND
    (
        -- Users active/logged in within last 365 days
        u.ActiveEnd BETWEEN  DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM,0,getdate())-12, 0) AND DATEADD(DD,-1,DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM,0,getdate()), 0))  
        --all Active Companies or Companies deactivated within the last 60 days
        OR c.ActiveEnd BETWEEN  DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM,0,getdate())-2, 0) AND DATEADD(DD,-1,DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM,0,getdate()), 0))
    )
```

If you want those values always included instead of excluded, just change the first `AND` to `OR`.

Also, remember that anywhere you want to assign a different default value to the dates that match 9999-01-01 you can use a case statement instead of just `u.ActiveEnd` like `case when u.ActiveEnd = '9999-01-01 00:00:00.000' then '1900-01-01' /* or whatever default you want */ else u.ActiveEnd end`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, you have saved my Time